Using Dialogflow Mensseger
I'm facing problems when I try customize my Dialogflow Mensseger app. I'm trying to create page with a chatbot, but no matter what I do, I can't do this without a bubble (the little botton on the right side).
enter image description here
I would apreciate if anyone could help me to break this out.
I looked all the documentation and I found that I can use the element df-messenger-chat to config how it is displayed on the page. However, I couldn't find a way to implement this.
